# safety disconnect oracle db from a jboss application

Tags: jboss, jndi, ibatis

I'm maintenance a old system it run in a jboss container,and it use ibatis and spring access an oracle db. Now this system's db related functions are discarded and the db will be closed. How should i do to safety disconnect this system with db (assuming the application code can deal with all exceptions except SqlException)
the key configuration is as follows:
xxx-ds.xml:

```
<datasources>
    ...
</datasources>
```

daoContext.xml:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="oracleSource" jndi-name="java:/DefaultDS"/>

<!-- SqlMap setup for iBATIS Database Layer -->
<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="META-INF/sql-map-config.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xxxx" class="path.to.class.xxxxDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleSource"/>
    <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient"/>
</bean>
```

path.to.class.xxxxDao is extends org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport and implements db access methods.

Answer (score 0):

Replace jndi data source with a mock db